# Finding different amount of network nodes between linux VM and raspberry pi

Tags: java, multithreading, networking, raspberry-pi

I have a Java application running on a raspberry pi. I developed it on my Mac or in a linux VM (parts in each) and it worked fine there. It also runs on the pi just fine but it shows me different results concerning the networking scanning functionality

What it does is it checks for its own IP address (e.g. 192.168.1.102), takes the subnet (192.168.1.) and then iterates over all possible IP addresses in that space. For each IP it sends a ping request (well actually a [isReachable()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#isReachable%28int%29) method for java. I give it a 150ms timeout (more than enough for a ping response in common local area networks).

Also I have it running in parallel in a threadpoolexecutor with 10 threads, each of them handling one IP address.

Now my problem: While it works fine and consistent on my VM/Mac (giving me a constant 10 nodes for example within a period of 30 minutes at home), it constantly fluctuates on the Pi:

```
### We found 2 nodes ###
### We found 6 nodes ###
### We found 4 nodes ###
### We found 7 nodes ###
### We found 5 nodes ###
### We found 4 nodes ###
### We found 4 nodes ###
### We found 3 nodes ###
### We found 7 nodes ###
### We found 5 nodes ###
### We found 2 nodes ###
```

(extract from my console output)

Here is the code for the Runnable:

```
public void doPing() {
    try {
        InetAddress.getByName(ip).isReachable(timeout);
    } catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace();}

}
```

and my service, which manages the threads:

```
public void pingAllInSubnet(int responseTimeout) {

    // create a pool of threads, 20 max jobs will execute in parallel
    ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(20);
    // submit jobs to be executing by the pool
    for (int i = 1;i<255;i++) {
        //build IP to ping
        final String ipToPing = subnet + "." + i;

        threadPool.submit(new DiscoveryRunnable(ipToPing, responseTimeout));
    }

    // once you've submitted your last job to the service it should be shut down
    threadPool.shutdown();

    //see if our threads are all done
    try {
        if(!threadPool.awaitTermination(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)){
            threadPool.shutdownNow();
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }
}
```

anyone got any ideas as to why there is such a messed up amount of ping responses on the Pi? could it be

- the bad wifi connection compared to the macbook
- the lack of performance (700mhz cpu vs quadcore)
- ...?

any help would be greatly appreciated! :)
kind regards

Answer (score 0):

Okay so the problem was somewhere else. There were always all nodes in the arp cache but I read it using this code:

```
public HashMap<String, NetworkNode> getAllDevicesFromArpCache() {
    HashMap<String, NetworkNode> nodes = new HashMap<String, NetworkNode>();
    for (String line : getArpTable()) {
        String[] nodeInfo = line.split(" +"); //regex to split all spaces
        // string is of form: <dnsname> (<ip>) at <macAddress> on en0 ifscope [ethernet]
        String dnsName = nodeInfo[0];
        String ipAddress = nodeInfo[1].substring(1, nodeInfo[1].length() - 1);
        String macAddress = nodeInfo[3];
        NetworkNode node = new NetworkNode(macAddress, dnsName, ipAddress);

        nodes.put(node.getMacAddress(), node);
    }


    return nodes;
}

private Set<String> getArpTable() {

    Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
    Process pr = null;

    //a regex pattern that lets us search the arp output for mac addresses
    Pattern macPattern = Pattern.compile("([0-9A-Fa-f]{2}[:-]){5}([0-9A-Fa-f]{2})");
    try {
        pr = rt.exec("arp -a");
        String arp = InputStreamHelper.getStringFromInputStream(pr.getInputStream());
        HashSet<String> nodes = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(arp.split("\n")));
        Iterator<String> it = nodes.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            String node = it.next();

            if (!macPattern.matcher(node).find()) {
                it.remove();
            }
        }


        //for(String node : nodes){System.out.println(node);}

        return nodes;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return new HashSet<String>();
    }

}
```

notice the "arp -a" ...once I changed this to "arp -an" it didnt try to resolve the nodes via dns before it sent them back so they are given back right away. it took the pi a while to get the dns responses that is why it sometimes only gave me a few and sometimes all of them...